# Attempting to deploy Rails app to Heroku - Application Error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm not sure why this is happening. I tried `heroku restart` and running `herok run rake db:migrate` as suggested by another SO thread, but it didn't work.

Just to clarify, my application works fine on localhost.

HEROKU LOGS:

```
2014-03-23T21:07:47.989154+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
2014-03-23T21:07:47.989154+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-03-23T21:07:47.989709+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2014-03-23T21:07:47.989883+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
2014-03-23T21:07:47.989883+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
2014-03-23T21:07:47.989709+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2014-03-23T21:07:47.989883+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2014-03-23T21:07:47.989883+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
2014-03-23T21:07:47.989883+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
2014-03-23T21:07:47.989709+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2014-03-23T21:07:47.989883+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
2014-03-23T21:07:47.989883+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
2014-03-23T21:07:47.989883+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2014-03-23T21:07:47.990048+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2014-03-23T21:07:49.415499+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-03-23T21:07:49.431611+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-03-23T21:07:49.431611+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-03-23T21:07:54.457611+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 51763 -e production`
2014-03-23T21:08:04.929404+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2014-03-23T21:08:04.929404+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2014-03-23T21:08:04.934429+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-23T21:08:04.929404+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2014-03-23T21:08:04.929404+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-03-23T21:08:04.934429+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.2.3/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:481:in `raise_no_secret_key': Devise.secret_key was not set. Please add the following to your Devise initializer: (RuntimeError)
2014-03-23T21:08:04.934429+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-23T21:08:04.934429+00:00 app[web.1]:   config.secret_key = '0964de5caa044bc2ff80ae8c6a0f635d8088b348014048dd7a822e5156b4abb76e6a67d2ad2b3a77ec34221815146e3ce8c09822ec3058af44f6c85ae53073e0'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.934429+00:00 app[web.1]: Please ensure you restarted your application after installing Devise or setting the key.
2014-03-23T21:08:04.929404+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.0.3 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:51763
2014-03-23T21:08:04.934429+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:341:in `instance_exec'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.934429+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:341:in `eval_block'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.934429+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:319:in `draw'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.934783+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.934783+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.934429+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.2.3/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:206:in `devise_for'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.934429+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.934783+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.934783+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.934783+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.934783+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:102:in `reload_routes!'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.935072+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.2.3/lib/devise/rails.rb:14:in `block in <class:Engine>'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.934783+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.935072+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.934783+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.934783+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.935072+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.935072+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:55:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.935072+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.935788+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.935072+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.935072+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.935788+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.935788+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.935788+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.935788+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.935788+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.935788+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.935788+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.935072+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.936062+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.936062+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.936062+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.936062+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.936062+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.935788+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.936062+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.936062+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.936062+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.937179+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.937179+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.937179+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.937179+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.937179+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.937179+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.936062+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.937179+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.937179+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.934783+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.938108+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.938108+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.937179+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.938108+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.935072+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `call'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.935072+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.935788+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.936062+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.937179+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
2014-03-23T21:08:06.548407+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-03-23T21:08:06.574231+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-03-23T21:08:07.873844+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=sixtasks.herokuapp.com request_id=7318cb7f-49d1-4d8a-bafd-e269821ce1bc fwd="173.35.60.133" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-03-23T21:08:08.324562+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=sixtasks.herokuapp.com request_id=f03ca9a7-b3a8-4c7e-b7d5-cd3d7b7a280e fwd="173.35.60.133" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-03-23T21:08:13.353853+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=sixtasks.herokuapp.com request_id=99ccb00a-d386-402d-8266-4b0e4dc39bc1 fwd="173.35.60.133" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-03-23T21:08:11.632076+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=sixtasks.herokuapp.com request_id=0e9f41d3-f213-4a26-9008-d8a5fad2d78a fwd="173.35.60.133" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-03-23T21:08:11.885694+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=sixtasks.herokuapp.com request_id=283244bb-5cde-4c39-8835-6b17cb031725 fwd="173.35.60.133" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-03-23T21:08:13.179142+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=sixtasks.herokuapp.com request_id=3ea65bb3-7620-497c-a006-d70eacddf0d8 fwd="173.35.60.133" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-03-23T21:13:46+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-03-23T21:14:19+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-03-23T21:14:19.669604+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-03-23T21:14:19.480299+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy e4f2c99 by andrew@gmail.com
2014-03-23T21:14:19.480401+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v8 created by andrew.louis93@gmail.com
2014-03-23T21:14:24.461087+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 22691 -e production`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this part is the relevant part.

```
2014-03-23T21:08:04.934429+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise- 3.2.3/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:481:in `raise_no_secret_key': Devise.secret_key was not set. Please add the following to your Devise initializer: (RuntimeError)
2014-03-23T21:08:04.934429+00:00 app[web.1]:   config.secret_key = '0964de5caa044bc2ff80ae8c6a0f635d8088b348014048dd7a822e5156b4abb76e6a67d2ad2b3a77ec34221815146e3ce8c09822ec3058af44f6c85ae53073e0'
2014-03-23T21:08:04.934429+00:00 app[web.1]: Please ensure you restarted your application after installing Devise or setting the key.
```

Seems like you have set secret key in your local host but not on your heroku client. Can you post your devise configuration file? If you are setting your secret key with

```
ENV['secret_key']
```

or something you need to do

```
heroku config:set secret_key=YOUR SECRET KEY HERE
```

For your heroku application to access it. Comment if you have any question!

**[Edit1] Add the following line yo your config/initializers/devise.rb**

config.secret_key = '0964de5caa044bc2ff80ae8c6a0f635d8088b348014048dd7a822e5156b4abb76e6a67d2ad2b3a77ec34221815146e3ce8c09822ec3058af44f6c85ae53073e0'

Comment: Thanks for your response! I didn't set a secret key myself. Which is the devise configuration file you are thinking of? The only references to a `config.secret_key` I found were in `config/initializers/secret_token.rb` and in `devise.rb` found in the same directory. Here are pasties to the two files respectively: http://ideone.com/OBE9L2 and http://ideone.com/oat6Ey

Comment: I added the solution to my post. Just add that line to your config/initializers/devise.rb!